# Error upgrading Deno

Tags: snap

Typed in `deno upgrade` and after telling me new version was found, displayed `error: No such file or directory (os error 2)`

Originally installed from snap if that matters.

I'm new to Ubuntu, so any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS & release, and I'm not sure what you're trying to upgrade; but why not `snap refresh`  (which will upgrade all of your installed snaps). or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: The deno snap will upgrade itself automatically when a new version is available. No human action is necessary.